# Find $\int\cos x \left(\cos x - 2\sin x \right) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int\cos x \left(\cos x  - 2 \sin x \right) dx$$

I've tried $t = \dfrac{\tan x}2$ but the calculation is very long. I've also tried to use trigonometry to divide the problem even further and then use substitution, still long calculation.

How would you solve this?

Comment: Multiply to get the sum of two functions. One looks like $2u'u$ and the other can be done by parts. In fact you probably already did it before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint :**
$$
\int\cos x \left(\cos x  - 2 \sin x \right) dx=\int\cos^2 x \ dx-\int2\sin x\cos x\  dx.
$$
The first integral in the RHS can be evaluated by using identity
$$
\cos^2x=\frac{1+\cos 2x}{2}
$$
and the second integral in the RHS can be evaluated by using identity
$$
\sin2x=2\sin x\cos x.
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$\int\cos x(\cos x - 2\sin x)dx = \int\cos^2x dx + \int-2\cos x \sin x dx.$$